# Help identifying 632A switching regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification

Help me identify this IC. Marking says
**632A
SCT 14C**
This must be switching voltage regulator, but I could not find the information about it.

[image]

Edit: this IC is used in the RC flight controllers by iFlight, T-Motor manufacturers. Identification might be usefull for anyone who plugged in the battery in reversed polarity or short-circuited anything.

Comment: Moderator asks: Please add some context information and anything known in more detail to please the vote-to-close-people. The answer is 99%++ likely  to be correct but that does not please some people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is it's an SCT2632A!

I have found it by a quick search on LCSC.com (no affiliation). I did a search on "632A" and tried to find the closest match. SCT seems to be the company making it.

I specifically went there, as it seems that the Blitz F7 flight controller is Chinese-designed, and that store has Chinese parts. :-)

[See here for the product listing.](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_SCT-SCT2632ASTER_C2916527.html)

[And here is the datasheet.](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2111121930_SCT-SCT2632ASTER_C2916527.pdf)

The pin-out seems to match reasonably well too:

[image: Example schematic from the datasheet]

My earlier guess would've been a MAX632 or a clone thereof, but the pin-out did not seem to match. That one too is a DC-DC converter chippo in a SOIC-8, but entirely pin-incompatible.

---

As an aside:

<sup>You can also easily find the on-board [AT7456E](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810301815_ZHONGKEWEI-AT7456E_C82351.pdf) in that store; which seems to be some OSD text generator. Presumably for FPV stuff? On further inspection, that one seems to be a clone of the Maxim MAX7456! On further further inspection, it is not a direct clone, it seems to have twice the character memory of the Maxim part. Still, the clone's datasheet does quite certainly borrow quite a few things from the Maxim one >:/</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for good find! This must be the SCT2632A! The datasheet says that package marking is the "632A" and the second line in the marking is "SCT".

Comment: As for the AT7456E - it is indeed the OSD chip widely used on the FPV devices to overlay the text and pseudo graphics on the camera video feed. Yes, it is the clone of the Maxim MAX7456. But this is the case when the clone is better! Not only the character memory is increased, but the current draw is decreased almost the twice! Original MAX7456 draws 107mA (!) and the clone AT7456 draws 51.3mA according to the datasheet. Also the AT7456 can be powered from 3.15V  while the MAX7456 from 4.75V. So AT7456 can work on the 3.3V power line. Not to mention that it is times cheaper.